# spin glowing image using css

Tags: html, css, css-animations

How can I make this Image with infinite glow animation to spin at the same time using css. Am trying to use two animations at once.
I want to make it spin indefinitely.

```css
.topbar-artwork img{
  animation: glowing 600ms infinite;
}

@keyframes glowing {
  0% { box-shadow: 0 0 -10px #000; }
  40% { box-shadow: 0 0 20px #000; }
  60% { box-shadow: 0 0 20px #000; }
  100% { box-shadow: 0 0 -10px #000; }
}
```

```html
<div class="topbar-artwork">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/0INjJXJ.jpg">
  </div>
```

Comment: Please don't forget to accept an answer if there is one that solves your issue, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply add another animation:

```css
.topbar-artwork img {
  animation: glowing 600ms infinite,
             spin 2s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes glowing {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0px #000;
  }
  40% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #000;
  }
  60% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #000;
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0px #000;
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="topbar-artwork">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/0INjJXJ.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To implement the rotation function, use the css property `transform: rotate(deg)`

```css
    .topbar-artwork img{
  animation: glowing 600ms infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes glowing {
  0% { box-shadow: 0 0 -10px #000; transform: rotate(0deg);}
  40% { box-shadow: 0 0 20px #000; }
  60% { box-shadow: 0 0 20px #000; }
  100% { box-shadow: 0 0 -10px #000; transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

```html
    <div class="topbar-artwork">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/0INjJXJ.jpg">
      </div>
```